# regarding include-exclude links in user-scripts

Tags: userscripts

Question regarding include-exclude links in user-scripts :

Type of pages I like to exclude:
http://www.stumbleupon.com/stumbler/samira-reddy/likes/interest

Type of pages I like to include:
http://www.stumbleupon.com/stumbler/samira-reddy

Note : I am a regular guy , don't know any coding stuff
what I tried but ain't work:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           run imacro shortcut which click stumble button on pages
// @namespace      udit
// @include        http://www.stumbleupon.com/interest/*
// @include        http://www.stumbleupon.com/channel/*
// @include        http://www.stumbleupon.com/stumbler/*
// @exclude        http://www.stumbleupon.com/stumbler/*likes/interest
// ==/UserScript==
```

Comment: no worry man ! i find the solution

Comment: What is the solution you found?  Post it in an answer, maybe it will help someone else in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// @exclude        http://www.stumbleupon.com/stumbler/*/likes/interest/*
```